# Merging Multiple tables while having different data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables that I want to join and merge. The problem is there might be some data in a table that doesn't exists in the other one, therefore a simple join wouldn't get the job done.

Here is an example:

```
Table1                  Table 2                 Table 3
-----------------       -----------------       -----------------
FoodTitle   CountA      FoodTitle   CountB      FoodTitle   CountC      
Food1       2           Food1       7           Food2       7
Food2       5           Food3       4           Food5       9
Food3       4           Food4       10          Food6       11
```

And the desired result is:

```
FoodTitle   CountA      CountB      CountC
------------------------------------------
Food1       2           7           Null
Food2       5           Null        7
Food3       4           4           Null
Food4       Null        10          Null
Food5       Null        Null        9
Food6       Null        Null        11
```

As shown above, I want to merge these three tables with the 'FoodTitle' column, and have the null columns in the result. There are more columns in these tables which I omitted them to simplify this example, but I want to have them as well in the result, with the same logic that goes on here. Whether there is data in them or not, I want to have them in my result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @Nick it's in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, taking care to `JOIN` `table3` to the `COALESCE` `FoodTitle` from `table1` and `table2`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.FoodTitle, t2.FoodTitle, t3.FoodTitle) AS FoodTitle,
       t1.CountA, t2.CountB, t3.CountC
FROM Table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.FoodTitle = t1.FoodTitle
FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.FoodTitle = COALESCE(t1.FoodTitle, t2.FoodTitle)
```

Output

```
FoodTitle   CountA  CountB  CountC
Food1       2       7       (null)
Food2       5       (null)  7
Food3       4       4       (null)
Food4       (null)  10      (null)
Food5       (null)  (null)  9
Food6       (null)  (null)  11
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cd85c/3)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a union followed by an aggreagation by food type:

```
SELECT
    FoodTitle,
    MAX(CountA) AS CountA,
    MAX(CountB) AS CountB,
    MAX(CountC) AS CountC
FROM
(
    SELECT FoodTitle, CountA, NULL AS CountB, NULL AS CountC FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FoodTitle, NULL, CountB, NULL FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FoodTitle, NULL, NULL, CountC FROM Table3
) t
GROUP BY
    FoodTitle
ORDER BY
    FoodTitle;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

An alternative to consider here would be a full outer join.  But given that you are dealing with three, not two, tables, you would need at least two joins, and that seems uglier than the union approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think since i have different number of columns in these tables, i got an error while implementing your solution: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: Then you're not running my code.  Check the demo, where it is working with your sample data.